# How to access Dungeon Crawl "morgue" (files for past games)?

Tags: files, directory, games, hidden-files

I recently got a small game from Software Center called Dungeon Crawl and I can't figure out how to view my past games. It says the morgue file (of game'overs) is in the `/home/owner/.crawl/morgue/` directory, but I can't find it at all. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. How can I find this directory?

Answer (score 5):

In those instructions, **`owner`** (or `<owner>`) is intended to be replaced by your username. When you first open the file browser, you'll be in your home folder (`/home/owner`). So you just have to navigate into the `.crawl` folder.

Files and folders that start with a `.` are hidden by default. To show them in Nautilus (the file browser), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or do `View` > `Show Hidden Files`. Then you can navigate into the `.crawl` folder inside your home directory, where (assuming the documentation you read is correct) there should be a `morgue` folder that contains your past games.

Comment: This is correct, the text files can be a bit confusing to read thought, there will be 3 for each character,  "lst" which is the things that were left on the dungeon floor, "txt" = character stats, skills and inventory, and "map" = a text based map